# jQuery: Retrieving the next links hash value in list

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to retrieve the hash value of the next link

HTML

```
<ul id="links">
    <li><a href="index.php?#1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?#2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?#3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('#links li a').click(function() {

    var current_link = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
    var next_link = $(this).next().attr("href").substring(1);

});
```

The current_link works, but I can't seem to retrieve the value of the link below. I think i'm missing an index() somewhere but i'm not exactly sure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#links li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var current_link = this.hash.slice(1);
    var next_link = '';
    if ($(this).parent().next().length > 0)
       next_link = $(this).parent().next().find('a')[0].hash.slice(1);

    alert('this: ' + current_link + ' next: ' + next_link);
    //return false;

});​
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nnaj6/1/)

Comment: Didn't know the native link had a `hash` property! Thanks! +1

Comment: One question: Does it make more sense to use substr(1) if I don't want the '#' in the string?

Comment: @Ryan: `substring(1)` would give you `ndex.php?#1`. But you can use `hash.substring(1)`.

Comment: @Ryan - you could use `.slice(1)` to erase the `#`. for example, `current_link.slice(1)` would return `1` if you click the first link.

Comment: @Ryan - I updated my answer. It solves the problem when there's no next link. ;)

Comment: Hrm, now i'm getting an "Unexpected Token ILLEGAL" when i drop this into my code.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in the (Chrome (Development Tools)) console

Comment: does the demo I put above gave you that too ?

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.next()` function to get the next sibling, for example, the next sibling of #1 would be #2.

### Docs

http://api.jquery.com/next/

### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/U7G6h/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var next_link = $(this).parent().next().children('a').first().attr("href").substring(1);
```